# タブレット上でPowerpointを使う際に、コンテキストメニューを非表示にしたい

Tags: c#, powerpoint

今までユーザがマウスでPowerpointを使うことを想定して、Powerpointのアドインシステムを開発してきましたが、ここ最近ユーザがタブレット上でPowerpointを使うことを想定して開発することになりました。

そこで直面した問題は、今までマウスでは反応した`WidnowBeforeRightClick`イベントが
タブレット上のタッチでは反応しなくなったことです。

てっきり私は、マウスの右クリック==長押しタッチ だと思って開発していましたが、
いくらタブレット上で長押しをしても`WindowBeforeRightClick`イベントは全く反応してくれません。

`WidowBeforeRightClick`イベントがタブレット上で反応してくれなければ、
長押しによって表示されるコンテキストメニューを非表示にできません。

どうすればいいのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

ちなみに、`WindowBeforeRightClick`イベント周辺のコードは以下のようになっています。

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WindowBeforeRightClick += 
        new PowerPoint.EApplication_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(Application_WindowBeforeRightClick);
    }

    internal void Application_WindowBeforeRightClick(PowerPoint.Selection Sel, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("コンテキストメニュー:非表示");   
    }
```